# Web form integrate with views

Tags: views, webforms

I working on project where user search for nearest shop. so configured view and output result  user get list of shops. in that result I want to provide a button **Email us** and when user click on that button have to one form will appear and user fill up the data and click on **SEND**, Then that mail should be send to the shopkeeper`s mail id and also to the user who sent it.
**I want to display a button on every single result with fetching mail field according to user into webform**
I used [profil2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) for user profile and  [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) modules.

Answer (score 0):

we have a [webform views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_view)
which may help you I suppose

Comment: Thanks for your response I configured this module but not fulfill my project requirement , but I got something same like my test case on http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/webform-passing-info-through-url.